# Does water evaporated from sea water contains any salts in it?

Tags: water, safety, food-chemistry

I want to know whether water evaporated from sea water is liable for drinking or not?

Comment: Related: [Vaporized sodium hydroxide?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/31569/7951)

Answer (score 1):

Water evaporated from sea water is water vapour. After condensation it is just pure water and **no** dissolved salts. It should be okay for drinking !

Answer (score 0):

Distilled water is pure water, right? Evaporation + condensation = distillation. Thus your condensed water must be pure, salt-free and good for drinking purposes. I am assuming, of course, that the pieces of equipment one uses to evaporate and condense the H2O are exempt from impurities, so that during its transit through the condenser the water does not get contaminated by such undesired substances, whatever they may be.

As a side note, distilled water is tasteless and will not quench one's thirst as mineral water would.

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to desalinate it to get rid of the salts.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desalination